# Algorithm to calculate new position of items in a list

Tags: algorithm, list, time-complexity

Assume there is an unsorted list of items, and we know the initial position (index) of every item in the list. Now we start to perform insertion and deletion operations. Once all operations are done, I want to be able to calculate the new index of the item that was in the n-th position.

For example. Assume we have the following list:

```
['a', 'x', 'b', 'w', 'e'].
```

We perform the following operations (indices are zero based):

- Insert 'u' at 3
- Delete at 5
- Insert 'j' at 0
- Delete at 1

The new list is:

```
['j', 'x', 'b', 'u', 'w']
```

and I want to know the new index of the item that was at index 3 ('w' - the answer is 4).

Of course, I can always loop through the list and find the index of 'w' - which would require O(N).

I am looking for an algorithm that will provide the answer to "what is the new position of the item that was at position n". The algorithm may add O(1) calculations to the Insert and Remove operations. When asked, the algorithm should return the new position of an item, in less than O(N). (O(log n) perhaps, or even O(1) if its possible).

**Edit**
Just to be more specific. The algorithm I am looking for starts after the set of modifications is done. We can have a one time setup that creates a data structure, which can later be queried for the new position of an item given it's original position. Assume the size of the list is N, the number of operations was M. Also assume K = Max(N, M).

- Setup time may take O(k*log K), but preferably take O(K) is possible.
- Single Query time should take less than O(K) (for example O(log K) or O(1))

Also, the algorithm can assume that all queries look for items that are still in the list.

Comment: You only need to do bookkeeping here. If something is removed *after* that element, nothing changes for the index, if something is removed *before* that element, the index is decremented (the same for insert, although here with increment). So you can iterate just over the instructions, without taking the real list into account.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem note that I am not trying to follow a specific item. I want to be able to ask about any item once the insertions and deletions are done. If I need to do bookkeeping for all elements in the lists at each insertion and delete - it turns it into a O(N) operation.

Comment: no, you just need to remember the instructions, and thus iterate through the instructions once for every element you want to calculate.

Comment: So that's O(M) where M = the number of operations. It may actually be larger than N

Comment: it makes not much sense that an algorithm is smaller than its *input size* (not to be confused with *state size*), since otherwise the input was irrelevant in the first place. A algorithm where you would actually do the operations on the list, would be *O(M N)*.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. You may have a list of size - n - that goes through m modifications. I am ok with O(1) overhead on each modification as it happens, as long as I can calculate the new position of any element in less than linear time. Both inputs - the original list, and the set of operations - are relevant.

Comment: if you *remove* an element from a list with *n* elements, it takes *O(n)* operations (you need to shift all elements at the right of that element one place to the left), the same with inserting (shift elements one to the right). If there are *m* modifications, and each take *n* instructions, we thus have an *O(m n)* algorithm.

Comment: You can keep track of the adjustments to each item's position using a binary tree, which would allow you to return the new position in O(log n), however this would also add O(log n) time to each insert and remove operation.

Comment: You didn't mention the case of a removed item: what should be the answer of the final position of the item which was initially at index 2, if the first action was 'remove item 2'...?

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying. Maybe I should correct my phrasing. We are not trying to run a single question of "what is the new index of". We are trying to create a data structure that can answer this question for many items.

Assume that you have a list with 1000 items, and you make 100 changes. Now I want to get the new position of O(N) items. If it takes O(M) to calculate the new position of each one, it will take O(N*M) altogether. And this is what I am trying to reduce.

Comment: @CiaPan - You can assume this will never be asked.

Comment: @samgak - Sounds promising. I would love to see more details. I am not sure what should be kept in the binary tree after each insertion and deletion

Comment: @KobiHari based on your clarification above I'm not sure it's the best way after all. If you want to get the new index of all N original elements (as opposed to randomly querying the new position of a subset of them), you can store the original index in the list (along with the element value). Iterate over the list once the insertions and removals have been done, incrementing a count to keep track of the new position and comparing with the stored initial position for each element.

Comment: @samgak But your idea has the benifit that it is continous. So I can also make queries after only a subset of the operations and the additional setup would not require O(N) calculations after each operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an algorithm to do this in `O(log n)` per operation and `O(1)` per query. We store the elements in an [implicit treap](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/treap.html) (or some other similar cartesian tree structure), which allow insertions, deletions, and access by index all in `O(log n)`. After we perform all the operations, we iterate over the implicit treap and construct a table of the positions of the elements. Then we can answer queries in `O(1)` as described in samgak's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your list structure to store the initial position of each element, for example storing a tuple of index, value instead of value for each element:

```
 ['a', 'x', 'b', 'w', 'e']
```

becomes

```
 [{'a', 0}, {'x', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'w', 3}, {'e', 4}]
```

Then run your insertions and removals, giving each new insertion an index of -1 to indicate that it wasn't in the original list:

```
 [{'j', -1}, {'x', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'u', -1}, {'w', 3}]
```

Now create an array 'newIndexArray' equal to the original list size, initialize all values to -1 and then iterate over the new list, incrementing a counter starting from zero to keep track of the new position. For each element, set:

```
 newIndexArray[elementTuple.Item2] = counter
```

`newIndexArray` will now containg the following values:

```
 newIndexArray[0] = -1
 newIndexArray[1] = 1
 newIndexArray[2] = 2
 newIndexArray[3] = 4
 newIndexArray[4] = -1
```

-1 means the element that was originally at that position has been removed.

Algorithm is O(N) for the entire list, or O(1) per element. There is O(1) additional cost per insertion and (initializing the index to -1)

Comment: Can you explain how 'the algortihm is O(N) _for the entire list_'? Depending on the list implementation, if it's linear (say, an expandable array) then each insertion and deletion is O(N) because it requires shifting half of the array data on average on each operation; if it's a dynamic structure (like a linked list) it requires searching the place to modify, again O(N). That would make O(NM) in total. Do you mean representation with a hash-map or something else?

Comment: @CiaPan I mean that "the algorithm to calculate new position of items in a list" (which takes place after the list has been modified) is O(N). The time complexity of the insertion and removal operations will depend on the list implementation (the question is agnostic on that point).